# Create file in My Documents folder from Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, service

Excuse me if this seems obvious but I'm rather new on it

I'm trying to create a file from a Windows Service into My Documents folder but instead I ending up creating it in C:\

Here's the code:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments) + @"\" + name +".txt";
```

Any idea why?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample search: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+service+specialfolder+wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `Environment.GetFolderPath()` is returning an empty string, therefore your path variable starts with '\' which is the root of your drive. This could happen because you're running your service as a user that doesn't have a profile defined.

Comment: 2 hours cracking my head reading here and there about this and you solved it in 7 minutes... outstanding! THANKS logix! It did the trick! :D